# Does Spark SQL use Cassandra secondary indexes?

Tags: indexing, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

We use Cassandra to store a number of analytics tables, eg "user clicks", "user logins" etc. Our data model is designed in such a way that our application always queries by the partition key, eg "get logins for user id" etc. Sometimes, however, we need to do some adhoc analysis like "what's was the average number of logins per user per month over the last 6 months?" and for that we use Spark SQL.

My question is this: my understanding is that Spark SQL will basically iterate over every row in Cassandra and apply the conditions of the SQL query to each row, discarding those that don't match and returning those that do match (and finally applying any aggregation etc required). If I create a secondary index on a Cassandra column (for example, 'login time'), and then in Spark SQL I do something like "select * from logins where logintime > '2016-05-17'" will Spark SQL push the filtering down to Cassandra using the secondary index, or will it still iterate through every row? Is there some config I need to set to manually tell it which columns have indexes in order to push down the indexed predicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> will Spark SQL push the filtering down to Cassandra using the secondary index, or will it still iterate through every row?

Yes, SparkSQL will perform predicate push-down to CQL using secondary index, when it is available

> Is there some config I need to set to manually tell it which columns have indexes in order to push down the indexed predicates?

The only thing you need to declare is activate predicate push down

1) Using **dataframe**

```
val df = sqlContext
  .read
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map( "table" -> "words", "keyspace" -> "test", "pushdown" -> true ))
  .load()
```

2) Using pure **SparkSQL**

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE words
USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
OPTIONS (table "words", keyspace "test", pushdown "true")
```

The connector will fetch the metadata from Cassandra at bootstrap and will figure out automatically which indices can be used for pushdown

Comment: Ah, the pure SparkSQL was the bit I was missing - amazing, thanks! Presumably this will work with Spark's HiveThriftServer for SparkSQL?

Comment: Hi @doanduyhai, I tried. However, it seems that indexed column were not pushed down... I also cannot find any document on spark-cassandra-connector mentioning  this behavior. Appreciate if you can redirect to the right doc / source code.